# Requisição AJAX retornando erro 415

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

Sou novato no desenvolvimento WEB e estou com um pequeno problema

criei um Webservice em Java com apenas um método para teste que soma dois valore recebidos por parâmetros da requisição. segue ele:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "WSProtocolo")
public class WSProtocolo {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "soma")
    public Integer soma(@WebParam(name = "x") Integer x, @WebParam(name = "y") Integer y) {
        System.out.println("Funcionou");
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

e Aqui o Ajax que faz a requisição:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WSProtocolo?wsdl/soma",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({parametro1: 25, parametro2: 5}),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data + ", Sucesso!");
    }
});
```

no Debug do chrome ele só retorna o erro

> 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

alguém saberia me dizer oque está errado?

Comment: Porque voce esta usando stringify no `data:` ?